# Google Analytics - Custom Dimension value not reflecting in reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, custom-dimensions

I have some custom dimensions created for other reports and data is collected and displaying fine.
Recently I have created a new Dimension with name "UserId" with index 13, type as "Hit".

From my code - I have a common JavaScript variable which will pass the value to GTM and which will in turn fire the tag.
IN my GTM tag I have set the custom dimension index 13 to this JS variable.
In this JS variable - value is being recorded and even in Google analytics collect method, I can see the value of **cd13**, but in my google analytics - under Behaviour --> Events --> overview, when I select the event which has the data for this dimension, and select this dimension under secondary dimension, but it is not showing any records, though the value has been passed for this dimension.

Not sure where I am missing something. Its been 20 hours still I data is not reflecting in custom dimension.

**GTM Tag setup**[image: GTM Tag Set up]

**GA collect**[image: GA Collect]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For someone who is looking for similar issue - I figured out that the dimension was working after 2 days.